# Spark-Elasticsearch Connectivity Issue

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have a code piece that should index data to Elasticsearch,

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('ES_indexer').getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([{'num': i} for i in xrange(10)])
df = df.drop('_id')
df.write.format('es').option('es.nodes', '3.45.67.131').option('es.nodes.wan.only','true').option('es.port', 9200).option('es.resource', '%s/%s' % ('index_name', 'doc_type_name')).save()
```

However, when I execute this as a spark submit job using,

```
 spark-submit --packages org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-hadoop:7.2.0 test-chetan.py
```

I get an error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/tmp/test-chetan.py", line 5, in <module>
    df.write.format('es').option('es.nodes', '3.45.67.131').option('es.nodes.wan.only','true').option('es.resource', '%s/%s' % ('index_name', 'doc_type_name')).save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 732, in save
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o49.save.
: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: [HEAD] on [index_name] failed; server[3.15.27.191:9200] returned [503|Service Unavailable:]
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.checkResponse(RestClient.java:469)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.executeNotFoundAllowed(RestClient.java:439)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.exists(RestClient.java:529)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.indexExists(RestClient.java:524)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.isEmpty(RestRepository.java:466)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ElasticsearchRelation.isEmpty(DefaultSource.scala:625)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

19/07/19 21:27:51 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
19/07/19 21:27:51 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://ip-172-31-40-1.us-east-2.compute.internal:4041
19/07/19 21:27:51 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
19/07/19 21:27:51 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
19/07/19 21:27:51 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
19/07/19 21:27:51 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
19/07/19 21:27:51 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
19/07/19 21:27:51 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
19/07/19 21:27:51 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
19/07/19 21:27:51 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/tmp/spark-d23384c9-63c3-4875-a254-d403226cccdd/pyspark-5bc00e36-b585-4c18-96c2-59aa20848db2
19/07/19 21:27:51 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/tmp/spark-d23384c9-63c3-4875-a254-d403226cccdd
19/07/19 21:27:51 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/tmp/spark-605e10a6-0232-4f55-855d-a04ef83fa886
```

I am not quite able to debug the cause of this line,

```
: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: [HEAD] on [index_name] failed; server[3.15.27.191:9200] returned [503|Service Unavailable:]
```

My AWS Elasticsearch is publicly accessible and EMR, where spark is deployed, has all access to egress so I don't believe its a security issue.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify all the nodes of your ES cluster under the 'es.nodes' configuration.

When you set 'es.nodes.wan.only' to 'true' you are preventing the connector from accessing nodes that were not specified in 'es.nodes'

Or you could set 'es.nodes.wan.only'=false

**es.nodes.wan.only (default false)-**

Whether the connector is used against an Elasticsearch instance in a cloud/restricted environment over the WAN, such as Amazon Web Services. In this mode, the connector disables discovery and only connects through the declared es.nodes during all operations, including reads and writes. Note that in this mode, performance is highly affected."

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/master/configuration.html

Comment: 1. Are you using the server's public or private ips?, can you confirm that the IP that shows you the error is of the same type as the one you're accessing (public/private).                                                                                                               2. What Spark version are you using? if its Spark 1 then please try with Spark2.       Assuming you have it installed, you can opt to use it like this : 'export SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2' @ChetanYadav

Comment: I'm using the public ip, tried it with private as well. No luck. Yes, the IP being shown is the same as the one i'm trying to access. Spark 2.4.2 is being used.